# Data storage is about to finish and want to remove Email Tracking Statistics

Tags: managed-package, data-loader, delete-managed-package

We are running short of data storage and I can see most od the data storage used by "Email Tracking Statistics" almost 44%. I tried to delete it but I haven't get any option to delete. We were using campaign monitor earlier and this object created by campaign monitor. I tried data loader but did not get any object related this. It a manage package so how can I remove data.

Please help if any one was running with this issue.

Comment: Check whether you have manage package access or not for your login

Comment: Manage Package name is Campaign monitor and It's expired and no user associated from it.  @highfive